# How can optimize these instruction with MYSQL (subqueries for each row)?

Tags: mysql

My problem is that we make a select, and then, for each row, we run 4 differents request SQL (is madness), as you can guess we make a lot of requests, and the system using this is very slow.

```
SELECT 
    deal_source.id, 
    deal_source.source_name, 
    deal_source.spider_status, 
    spider.last_success_date
FROM deal_source 
JOIN spider 
ON deal_source.id = spider.deal_source_id
```

Then for each row of this query we make:

```
$total_query = "SELECT count(id) as total
                FROM spider_log 
                WHERE deal_source_id = '$deal_source_id' 
                AND date_format(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$lastdate' ";

$added_query = "SELECT count(id) as added
                FROM spider_log 
                WHERE deal_source_id = '$deal_source_id' 
                AND action = 'added'  
                AND date_format(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$lastdate' ";

$extended_query = "SELECT count(id) as extended 
                   FROM spider_log 
                   WHERE deal_source_id = '$deal_source_id' 
                   AND action = 'extended'  
                   AND date_format(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$lastdate' ";

$duplicate_query = "SELECT count(id) as duplicate 
                    FROM spider_log 
                    WHERE deal_source_id = '$deal_source_id' 
                    AND action = 'duplicate'  
                    AND date_format(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$lastdate' ";
```

Comment: And I guess the `spider.last_success_date` from the 1st query is passed to the other 4 as `'$lastdate'`?

Comment: Please also clarify on the datatypes of `date_created` and `last_success_date` columns. Are they `DATE`, `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT   d.id,
         d.source_name,
         d.spider_status,
         s.last_success_date,
         COUNT(l.id) AS total,
         SUM(l.id IS NOT NULL AND l.action='added'    ) AS added,
         SUM(l.id IS NOT NULL AND l.action='extended' ) AS extended,
         SUM(l.id IS NOT NULL AND l.action='duplicate') AS duplicate
FROM     deal_source d
    JOIN spider      s
      ON s.deal_source_id  = d.id
    JOIN spider_log  l
      ON l.deal_source_id  = d.id
      ON l.date_created   >= s.last_success_date
     AND l.date_created   <  s.last_success_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY
GROUP BY d.id
```

Comment: I think you also need to join the `spider` so you can use `spider.last_success_date` in place of `$lastdate`.

Comment: @eggyal: are we guaranteed that "`last_success_date`" is not datatype DATETIME or TIMESTAMP, and that it doesn't include any non-midnight time portion? (What we don't see in the OP code is whether any returned time portion is being whacked off to set `$last_date`.)

Comment: @spencer7593: Good point.  If necessary, one will need to apply the [`DATE()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function.

Comment: yes is text!, I replaced fot his two lines the last two:

      ON  DATE_FORMAT(l.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d')    >=  DATE_FORMAT(s.last_success_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
     AND DATE_FORMAT(l.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d')   <  DATE_FORMAT(s.last_success_date, '%Y-%m-%d') + INTERVAL 1 DAY


but I'm having an error:

Error Code: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON  DATE_FORMAT(l.date_created, '%Y-%m-%d')    >=  DATE_FORMAT(s.last_success_da' at line 14 (  ON s.deal_source_id  = d.id)

Comment: @spencer7593: The `+ INTERVAL` expression [will implictly cast strings to datetimes](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6274/1/0).

Answer (score 3):

Some points:

- You can optimize performance of each query, using `EXPLAIN` and the careful adding of indexes.
- You can combine all the queries to a big one, so you don't have to hit the database with a lot of queries.
- Besides the lots of queries, The `date_format(date_created, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$lastdate'` is a performance killer because it apples a function (`DATE_FORMAT()`) to a column (`date_created`) so no index can be used and the function is called thosuand or million of times (as many rows are examined). Change such conditions - wherever they are in your code - to:

  ```
   (  date_created >= DATE('$lastdate') 
  AND date_created < DATE('$lastdate') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   )
  ```

  or even better, if that `$lastdate` is a date, to:

  ```
   (  date_created >= '$lastdate' 
  AND date_created < '$lastdate' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
   )
  ```

  and even more better, if `date_created` is a `DATE` column, to:

  ```
      date_created = '$lastdate'
  ```

Comment: If I combine all the queries in a big one, how can I separate later the results?

Comment: With "combine" I mean something like @eggyal's answer.

Comment: +1. when i read your answer, it left me wanting something _even more better-er_